# Symfony Form render with Self Referenced Entity

Tags: forms, symfony, self-reference

I have an Entity containing Self-Referenced mapping.

```
class Category
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;

}
```

In my CategoryType I have this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $plan = $this->plan;

    $builder->add('name');

    $builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'xxxBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose a parent category',
        'required' => false,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($plan) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.plan = :plan')
                ->setParameter('plan', $plan)
                ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
        },
    ));
}
```

Actually, when I render the form field Category this is something like

- Cat1
- Cat2
- Cat3
- Subcat1
- Subcat2
- Cat4

I would like to know if it's possible and how to display something more like, a kind of a simple tree representation :

- Cat1
- Cat2
- Cat3
- -- Subcat1
- -- Subcat2
- Cat4

Regards.

Comment: Can you share your rendering codes?

Comment: I'd say you should use [Tree Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md). Because it avoid you headaches with nested entities. However, I'm not sure it will solve your problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something which seems correct from what you and [jperovic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24188121/1338574) wrote. You will need two new attributes for your `Category` class :

- `$level` will contain ID's of its parents like "idA-idB", etc. this attribute will be use to sort your results when querying your database so you can be certain SubCatOf3 won't come before Cat3 !
- `$treeName` will contain what [jperovic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24188121/1338574) already wrote and will be printed in the form.

I also used Doctrine Events [[doc]](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) so when you update/persist them,  you don't have to worry about the value of these attributes.

This is your brand new `Category.php` file :

```
/**
* @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks()
*/
class Category 
{

    private $level;

    private $treeName;

    /** 
    * Renders something like : "---- Subcategory A" 
    * @ORM\PreUpdate() 
    * @ORM\PrePersist()
    **/
    public function updateTreeName()
    {
       $itemDepth = 0;
       $parent = $this->parent;
       while ($parent != null) {
           $itemDepth++;
           $parent = $parent->getParent();
       }

       $this->treeName = str_repeat('--', $itemDepth) . ' ' . $this->name
    }

    /** renders something like : "idParent-idChild1-idChild2" 
    * @ORM\PreUpdate() 
    * @ORM\PrePersist()
    **/
    public function updateLevelName()
    {
       $this->level = '';
       $parent = $this->parent;
       while ($parent != null) {
           $parent = $parent->getParent();
           $this->level .= '-' . $p->getId();
       }
     }

    public function getTreeName()
    {
       return $this->treeName;
    }

    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->level; 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, put your **query_builder** in your `CategoryRepository.php` like this :

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
    public function getHierarchicalCategoryList($plan)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->where('u.plan = :plan')
           ->setParameter('plan', $plan)
           ->orderBy('u.level', 'ASC');

        $return $qb;
    }
}
```

And in your `CategoryType.php` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $plan = $this->plan;

    $builder->add('name');

    $builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'xxxBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'treeName',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose a parent category',
        'required' => false,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($plan) {
            return $er->getHierarchicalCategoryList($plan)
        },
    ));
}
```

**Note** : this is quick&dirty work so you might need to correct typos, annotations, etc. Yet, you have the idea ! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really long shot at best, but I think it could be achieved pretty easily.

Within your `query_builder` you specified the `'property' => 'name'`. You would need to change it to `'treeName'`. Doctrine will try to find and invoke property's `getter` method - that's where all the printing logic comes in:

```
class Category
{
    .... 
    Everything else
    ....

    public function getTreeName(){
        $itemDepth = 0;
        $p = $this->parent;
        while ( $p != null ){
            $itemDepth++;
            $p = $p->getParent();
        }

        return str_repeat('--', $itemDepth) . ' ' . $this->name
    }
}
```

This could pose a serious performance hit due to need to iterate for each item the `depth` times.

What do you think? What is the average depth of items?

Just to be clear, `name` property and its getter and setter are to remain intact.

Comment: This doesn't prevent you from showing Cat1, Cat2, SubCatOf2, SubcatOf3, Cat3 from example. You can't be sure subcats will be shown just right after their parent category ;)

Comment: Indeed. Let me think if I can come up with something like that :)